# Issue on uploading Android App bundle on Google PlayConsole

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

[image]

I'm having issue on uploading new App bundle on Play console. I tried to upload for release and internal sharing as well but it gives an "unexpected error" as shown in image. Size of my bundle in 99,300kb which is less than allowed size. 
I export this unity project for both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture. Project also contains native android code.

Comment: did you saved anything as draft?

Comment: I think this issue is not related to the Google Play 64-bit requirement, have you try Microsoft Edge browser?

Comment: I haven't saved anything as draft @sasikumar

Comment: @pic yes same error is coming

Comment: This looks like an unexpected error, so you'll have to reach out to the Play Developer support to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @Pierre I tried reaching them last week but still haven't heard back from them. And my update is stuck because of this.